# redux-form's reduce bundle size technique throws error with Flow syntax

Tags: javascript, redux-form, flowtype, babel-plugin-transform-import

Following [How to reduce redux-form's bundle size?](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/faq/bundlesize.md/) guide here. I'm using the `babel-plugin-transform-imports` method.

However, that produces an error when using Flow types:

```
import type { FormProps } from 'redux-form'
```

Error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'redux-form/es/FormProps'
```

Not sure if this is a bug, a missing feature, mis-configuration or simply impossible combination.

It'd be nice to be able to use `import { ... } from 'redux-form'` syntax rather than the verbose `import ... from 'redux-form/es/...'` syntax along with Flow.

I think I can also do

```
import { propTypes } from 'redux-form'


type Props = { ...propTypes }
```

but I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. Thoughts/Solutions/Workarounds?

Comment: have you installed [redux-form](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm/redux-form_v5.x.x) definitions ?

Comment: Definitions? I'm not using typescript.

Comment: Flow has its definitions as well like typescript. Click on the link I have provided

Comment: @HarshVardhan The link you shared is for v5.x. I'm using v6 which supports Flow: `redux-form supports static typing with Flow. Flow should automatically import the types when you import the components and functions from redux-form. In addition, you may import types for all the props provided by redux-form to your components.`

Comment: Can you check if you have a flow-typed directory in your project with redux-form v6 definitions in it.

Comment: @HarshVardhan I see various types.js under `dist/es` folder. There is also `types.js.flow` which has the `FormProps` type. I guess the babel plugin should ignore `import type...` statements. The issue is happening as it is blindly transforming imports to `dist/ws/{member}` statements.